# Efficient way of getting big data from Hadoop into Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

As I am just starting out in the Big Data field, I am looking for advice on how it would be most efficient way to get some data into Spark in order to analyze it.

The SQL query is rather large, with multiple sub-queries, each with it's own "when", "group by" etc.
THe final data would have somewhere between 1 million and 20 million rows.

Is it the same thing (performance wise) if I run a spark sql query and save it into a dataframe using pyspark, or if I extract each subquery into different spark dataframes and use spark to do the grouping / filtering / etc. ?

For example, are these two methods equivalent on the amount of resources / time they use to process my data?

method 1:

```
df_final = spark.sql("""
With subquery 1 as(...),
     subquery 2 as(...),
     subquery 3 as(...),
     ...
                   
select * from subquery n
"""
```

method 2:

```
df1 = spark.sql(subquery 1)
df2 = spark.sql(subquery 2)
...

df_final = *spark manipulation of dataframes here"
```

I would appreciate any advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spark will create a DAG which should be equivalent in both cases. Performance should be the same in both cases.